# Extract Message-ID from a file

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following code that extracts the `Message-Id` in gathers them in a `Dataframe`.It works and gives me the follwing results :

[image]
This an example of the lines in the `dataframe` :

> Message-ID: <23272646.1075847145300.JavaMail.evans@thyme>

What I want to have is only the string after `<` character and the before `>`. Because `Message-ID` ends with `>`. Also I have some lines where the `Message-ID` value is empty. I want to delete these lines.

Here is the code that I wrote

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 f = open('C:\\Users\\hmk\\Desktop\\PFE 2019\\ML\\MachineLearningPhishing- 
 master\\MachineLearningPhishing-master\\code\\resources\\emails- 
 enron.mbox','r')
 line_num = 0
 e = []
 search_phrase = "Message-ID"
 for line in f.readlines():
 line_num += 1
 if line.find(search_phrase) >= 0:
    #line = line[13:]
    #line = line[:-2]
    e.append(line)
 f.close()
 dfObj = pd.DataFrame(e)
```

Comment: Can you post input data in text format not screenshot?

Comment: you mean the Dataframe?

Comment: so when the message isn't blank you have it inbetween < and > right? But what are those lines you mentioned for when the message is blank?

Comment: Yes. Or `mbox` file.

Comment: when Message-ID is blank , I've got lines with only `Message-ID:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is using regex and pandas DataFrame replace:

```
clean_df = df.replace(to_replace='\<|\>', value='', regex=True)
clean_df = clean_df.replace(to_replace='(Message-ID:\s*$)', value=np.nan, regex=True).dropna()
```

the first line of code is removing the < and >, assuming the msgs will only contain those two

the second is checking if there is a message id on the body, if not it will replace for NaN.

note that I used numpy.nan just to simplify the process of dropping the blank msgs

Answer (score 0):

You want a substring of your lines

```py
for line in f.readlines():
  if all(word in line for word in [search_phrase, "<", ">"]):
    e.append(line[line.find("<")+1:-1])
    #-1 suppose ">" as the last character
```

Use `in` to check if a string is inside another string
Use `find` to get the index of your pattern
Use `[in:out]` to get substring between your two values

Comment: it tells me that `'str' object has no attribute 'substring'
`

Comment: My bad, substring is in java, now written in python

Comment: Thanks , but the `<` at the beginning remains.Also I have some lines that are empty because in the mbox file the `Message-ID:` has no value

Comment: Updated post to consider each requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex which will extract the desired Message-ID for you.

So your first part for extracting the message id would be like below:

```py
import re # import regex 
s = 'Message-ID: <23272646.1075847145300.JavaMail.evans@thyme>'
message_id = re.search(r'Message-ID: <(.*?)>', s).group(1)
print('message_id: ', message_id)
```

Your ideal `Message ID`:

```py
>>> message_id: 23272646.1075847145300.JavaMail.evans@thyme>
```

---

So you can loop through your data end check for the regex like this:

```py
for line in f.readlines():
    line_num += 1
    message_id = re.search(r'Message-ID: <(.*?)>', line)
    if message_id:
        msg_id_string = message_id.group(1)
        e.append(line)
        # your other works
```

The `if message_id:` checks whether there is a match for your `Message-ID` and if it doesn't match it will return `None` and won't go through the if instructions.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "We want <This text inside only>. yes we do."
s2 = s[s.find("<")+1:s.find(">")]
print(s2) # Prints : This text inside only
# If you want to remove empty lines :
lines = filter(lambda x: x.strip(), lines)
```

filter goes through the whole lines, no need for a for loop that way.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion for you:

```py
import re
f = open('PATH/TO/FILE', 'r').read()
msgID = re.findall(r'(?<=<).*?(?=>)', f)
```